# Can't get IP from DHCP using PowerShell command Set-NetIPInterface

Tags: windows, powershell, tcp, dhcp, server-core

When I configure my Windows Server Core with `Sconfig` it's working well and get an IP from my DHCP server.

But it's not working with PowerShell. I'm using this command:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 2" -Dhcp Enabled
```

`ipconfig` result:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e432:65ae:f7a7:c350%4
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: `ipconfig /renew`?

Comment: An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet 2 : The requested address is not valid in its context.

Comment: Works in the second try ,thanks a lot you saved my day @AnsgarWiechers